# PHP Escaping ... How to do it? ... I need some basics

Tags: php, wordpress

The last few days I was googling around to get an idea about "**escaping**" in PHP.
I got some understanding, about it and why you have to escape things.

I have learned PHP, but we didn't learn anything about escaping.
I firstly heard about it a few weeks ago...

At the moment I make a project with wordpress. (plugin-dev)
The Code for the plugin is almost ready, but I haven't escaped anything!!!
I want to do it now, but with my knowledge it won't be correct.

There are several escaping-functions documented on php.net.
There are some escaping-functions included in wordpress. (esc_html(), esc_url(), esc_attr(), ...)

I have created a short meaningless code-sample, which also contains Wordpress i18n functions.

It would be a great help for me, if somebody could show me how to apply escaping based on the code-sample.

I would get an idea about it and adopt it on my project.

```
<h1><?php echo "This is my heading"; ?></h1>

<a href="<?php echo $url ?>"><?php _e( 'my link', 'TextDomain' ); ?></a>

<div class="panel panel-info<?php if ( $design_animation != " " ) { echo " animated " . $design_animation; } ?>">

  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">   
      <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> <?php _e( 'This is the panel-title', 'TextDomain' ); ?>   
    </h3>
  </div><!--/.panel-heading-->

  <div class="panel-body">

    <?php echo "<div class='alert " . $AlertClass . "'>" . $AlertText . "</div>"; ?>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="duration" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php _e( 'Duration', 'TextDomain' ); ?>:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-group">

          <select class="form-control <?php echo $class ?>" name="duration" id="duration" required<?php echo $FormElementState; ?>>

          <?php

            $query_sql=$ wpdb->prepare( "SELECT blabla ..." ,$variable );
            $query = $wpdb->get_results( $query_sql, ARRAY_A ); 

            foreach($query as $row) { echo "<option value='" . $row["duration"] . "'>" . $row["duration"] . "" . __( 'Minuten', 'TextDomain' ) . "</option>";

          ?>

          </select>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
  <?php echo $MyTextFromDatabase ?>
</textarea>
```

EDIT:

In the example above: The variable "$design_animation" comes from DB. The value is not editable by a user. It is used as class. Do I have to escape it?

The variable "$row["duration"]" is coming from DB. It is a calculated integer. Do I have to escape it?

In Wordpress there are functions for escaping i18n translations. i18n translations are always in my code and don't ever come from DB or a form. Why do they exist?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Where are the variables you are outputting coming from? Escaping is required when you don't know their value and could be malicious (typically when it's submitted by a user in a form, for example). If you set all of the variables here earlier in your code and know they're trustworthy and are not modified by a user, then you don't need to worry about escaping them. If they're set from a request parameter, like `$var = $_GET['var'];` then you must escape

Comment: Why do you want an extra explanation? The documentation of the php functions clearly point out for what purpose they are to be used.

Comment: OK, in the example above:
The variable "$design_animation" comes from DB. The value is not editable by a user. It is used as class. Do I have to escape it?
The variable "$row["duration"]" is coming from DB. It is a calculated integer. Do I have to escape it?
In Wordpress there are functions for escaping i18n translations. i18n translations are always in my code and don't ever come from DB or a form. Why do they exists?

Answer (score 0):

I Like to use [php heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), because I don't have to concern about escaping double/single quotes and it makes the code more readable, i.e.:

```
<?php
$url = "https://somesite...";
$someVar = _e( 'my link', 'TextDomain' );
echo <<< LOL
<h1>This is my heading</h1>
<a href="{$url}"><{$someVar}</a>
LOL
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data comes from user input and is processed within php code, you can escape it with [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.addslashes.php). (not necessary if magic_quotes_gpc is on)

If it comes from user input in order to save it into database, you might consider using prepared statements with PDO, or [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) with older APIs.

Comment: For writing into DB I use functions like " sanitize_text_field() . I don't think that addslashes-function is the only one to use in my example above. For "$design_animation" I would perhaps use esc_attr().
For "$row["duration"]" ?. And I'm completly unsure about the i18n translations ...

Comment: You're right about sanitize_text_field, as you're using Wordpress. esc_attr is good for $design_animation. For $row["duration"], it should be good as is. In your php code, just test your variable with is_numeric before adding it: